# C Program with fscanf() mysteriously stops working

Tags: c, windows, mingw

I have a program called test.c, and an input file called test.in. I'm trying to read two strings from the input file and output them to the console. I'm running Windows 7 but I'm compiling with MinGW using gcc.

This is my file test.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {

    FILE *fin = fopen ("test.in", "r");
    char  *one, *two;

    fscanf(fin, "%s %s", one, two);
    printf("%s\n%s", one, two);

    fclose(fin);
    return 0;
}
```

And this is my file test.in :

```
ONE
TWO
```

I go to MinGW, run "gcc -o test.exe test.c", everything compiles fine, but when I run test.exe, a pop-up comes up and says "test.exe has stopped working. Windows is trying to find a solution to the problem..."

Does anyone know why this is?

Comment: Turn up your compiler warnings, they'll tell you that `one` and `two` are uninitialised. Use `-Wall` with gcc. Also, `int main`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fscanf` is writing to the uninitialised pointers you pass it.  The effects of this are undefined but a crash is likely.  You need to allocate your char arrays before calling it:

```
#define MAX_LEN (32) /* change this as required */
char one[MAX_LEN];
char two[MAX_LEN];
fscanf(fin, "%s %s", one, two);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have pointers to chars but you haven't allocated any memory to store the strings.

Try using character arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `char* one` there has to be `char one[100]`, or some other number. And the user must not enter more letters than the size of `one` (minus 1 for string terminator). Currently the code is writing to some random place in memory. In such random cases anything can happen.